# How can I simultaneously iterate over a Rust HashMap and modify some of its values?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying Advent of Code in Rust this year, as a way of learning the language. I've parsed the input (from day 7) into the following structure:

```
struct Process {
    name: String,
    weight: u32,
    children: Vec<String>,
    parent: Option<String>
}
```

These are stored in a `HashMap<String, Process>`.  Now I want to iterate over the values in the map and update the parent values, based on what I find in the parent's "children" vector.

What doesn't work is

```
for p in self.processes.values() {
    for child_name in p.children {
        let mut child = self.processes.get_mut(child_name).expect("Child not found.");
        child.parent = p.name;
    }
}
```

I can't have both a mutable reference to the `HashMap` (`self.processes`) and a non-mutable reference, or two mutable references.

So, what is the most idiomatic way to accomplish this in Rust?  The two options I can see are:

1. Copy the parent/child relationships into a new temporary data structure in one pass, and then update the Process structs in a second pass, after the immutable reference is out of scope.
2. Change my data structure to put "parent" in its own HashMap.

Is there a third option?

Comment: It seems obvious to me that `self.processes` is a `HashMap<String, Process>`.

Comment: I'd probably go for `Vec<Process>`, and use `usize` as reference to other entries.  Could use a two-pass approach: first build a `HashMap<String, usize>` and fill `name` + `weight`, in the second pass fill `children` and `parent`.  Lots of possibilities :)

Comment: @Stefan: meh, I just don't like to work with incomplete code; I guess it is an ok question to reason about, though.

Comment: Another option would be to change the type of `parent` to `RefCell<Option<String>>` – this would allow to change the parent even if you only have a const reference.

Comment: Also note that you need to clone the string to copy it from `p.name` to `child.parent` – you can't move it out of the borrowed context (neither would you want to even if you could).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can grant internal mutability to the `HashMap`'s values using [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html):

```
struct ProcessTree {
    processes: HashMap<String, RefCell<Process>>,  // change #1
}

impl ProcessTree {
    fn update_parents(&self) {
        for p in self.processes.values() {
            let p = p.borrow();                    // change #2
            for child_name in &p.children {
                let mut child = self.processes
                    .get(child_name)               // change #3
                    .expect("Child not found.")
                    .borrow_mut();                 // change #4
                child.parent = Some(p.name.clone());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`borrow_mut` will panic at runtime if the child is already borrowed with `borrow`. This happens if a process is its own parent (which should presumably never happen, but in a more robust program you'd want to give a meaningful error message instead of just panicking).

I invented some names and made a few small changes (besides the ones specifically indicated) to make this code compile. Notably, `p.name.clone()` makes a full copy of `p.name`. This is necessary because both `name` and `parent` are owned `String`s.