# How can I create a HashMap with values moved from two other HashMaps?

Tags: rust, hashmap

I have two `HashMap<&str, String>` with the same keys and I wish to create one `HashMap` with same keys where the values are combined. I do not want to keep references to the first two `HashMap`s, but want to move the `String`s to the new `HashMap`.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Contact {
    phone: String,
    address: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut phones: HashMap<&str, String> = HashMap::new();
    phones.insert("Daniel", "798-1364".into());
    phones.insert("Ashley", "645-7689".into());
    phones.insert("Katie", "435-8291".into());
    phones.insert("Robert", "956-1745".into());

    let mut addresses: HashMap<&str, String> = HashMap::new();
    addresses.insert("Daniel", "12 A Street".into());
    addresses.insert("Ashley", "12 B Street".into());
    addresses.insert("Katie", "12 C Street".into());
    addresses.insert("Robert", "12 D Street".into());

    let contacts: HashMap<&str, Contact> = phones.keys().fold(HashMap::new(), |mut acc, value| {
        acc.entry(value).or_insert(Contact {
            phone: *phones.get(value).unwrap(),
            address: *addresses.get(value).unwrap(),
        });
        acc
    });

    println!("{:?}", contacts);
}
```

But I have an error

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:24:20
   |
24 |             phone: *phones.get(value).unwrap(),
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:25:22
   |
25 |             address: *addresses.get(value).unwrap(),
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=00d0a797dce8db8e9ab688af386a8be0)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`HashMap::get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) returns an `Option<&V>`, that is, a reference to the value inside the map. You cannot move out of a reference with `*` unless `V` implements `Copy`. You need a different method that moves the value out of the map, which is [`HashMap::remove`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.remove) (note that it returns `Option<V>`).

If you try to rewrite the same algorithm using `remove`, you'll get a different error:

```
    let contacts: HashMap<&str, Contact> = phones.keys().fold(HashMap::new(), |mut acc, value| {
        acc.entry(value).or_insert(Contact {
            phone: phones.remove(value).unwrap(),
            address: addresses.remove(value).unwrap(),
        });
        acc
    });
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `phones` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:22:79
   |
22 |     let contacts: HashMap<&str, Contact> = phones.keys().fold(HashMap::new(), |mut acc, value| {
   |                                            ------        ----                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
   |                                            |             |
   |                                            |             immutable borrow later used by call
   |                                            immutable borrow occurs here
23 |         acc.entry(value).or_insert(Contact {
24 |             phone: phones.remove(value).unwrap(),
   |                    ------ second borrow occurs due to use of `phones` in closure

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
```

This error is telling you that you can't mutate a data structure while iterating over it, because mutating the data structure may invalidate the iterator. [Sometimes you can solve this with interior mutability](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47737084/3650362), but in this case you don't need to do anything like that. Just call `phones.into_iter()` to move the phone numbers out of the map while you iterate. Then it's easy to use a `map` to create `(&str, Contact)` tuples and, finally, `collect` it all back into a `HashMap`.

```
    let contacts: HashMap<_, _> = phones
        .into_iter()
        .map(|(key, phone)| {
            (
                key,
                Contact {
                    phone,
                    address: addresses.remove(key).unwrap(),
                },
            )
        })
        .collect();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6e732f8970fc8b386c0236c572b3a38b)

Comment: I like [the `flat_map` version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ebab664c760d05b98ddd075895c1acab), myself.

Comment: What if some keys belong to `phones` but does not exist in `addresses`, I come across with a crash here. But I don't know to avoid that.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin What do you want to do with those keys though? Try Shepmaster's version with `flat_map`, which will simply skip them.

Answer (score 1):

The `zip` is your friend here. But the "business logic" here dictates that it only works for a sorted map. So you if can use `BTreeMap` instead of `HashMap`, the following would work:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut phones: BTreeMap<&str, String> = BTreeMap::new();
    ...

    let mut addresses: BTreeMap<&str, String> = BTreeMap::new();
    ...

    let contacts: BTreeMap<&str, Contact> = phones
        .into_iter()
        .zip(addresses.into_iter())
        .map(|((name, phone), (_, addr))| {
            (
                name,
                Contact {
                    phone: phone,
                    address: addr,
                },
            )
        })
        .collect();

    println!("{:#?}", contacts);
}
```

Comment: Yes but this look strange, and what case do you have two exact same size and key map ? why not create contact directly without create the two past map ?

Comment: Well, I take that such invariance is just the premise of OP.